# Jquery Accordion Is not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I do want to hide/show About-paragraph located in the header, just under navigation bar and I can not see what I am doing wrong.

So, When I click `<li class="navAbout"><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>` from top navigation bar I do want to show my about content below it; pushing down the main page content.

Please, See My Coding so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/bbmWK/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, than you have broken selector. Try this:

```
$('.aboutConteiner').slideDown(3200);
```

If youu need to close about pressing close button, use this:

```
$('.close').click(function() {
    close();
});

function close() {
    var sb = $('.aboutConteiner').slideUp(3200);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: '-=' + sb.data('height')
    }, 3000);
}
```

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/E9Bq2/1/).

Comment: That's great. Also, I am wondering if you know a good way to take off ".toggle" and make use of "<h2><a href="#" title="Close About" class="close">Close X</a></h2>" to close the " .aboutConteiner " Thank you!